# How to generate dataset for multi output keras model

Tags: python, pandas, keras

I followed the [code examples for structured data classification at keras.io](https://keras.io/examples/structured_data/) to build a model for classifying a rather simple model similar to the one in the example.

I wanted to extend the model to handle a second output, but I cannot use this model to train. The dataset is generated like it is done in the example (but with two results):

```
res1 = dataframe.pop("result1")
res2 = dataframe.pop("result2")
ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((dict(dataframe),(res1,res2)))
```

The model is also similar to the example but using a two-dimensional output:

```
x = layers.Dense(32, activation="relu")(all_features)
x = layers.Dropout(0.5)(x)
output = layers.Dense(2, activation="sigmoid")(x)
model = keras.Model(all_inputs, output)
model.compile("adam", "binary_crossentropy", metrics=["accuracy"])
```

It compiles, but when i try to run fit...

```
model.fit(train_ds,epochs=30)
```

I get an error message:

```
ValueError: logits and labels must have the same shape ((None, 2) vs (None, 1))
```

How can I prepare the dataset to meet the shape constraints?

Answer (score 1):

I believe you should use the *zip()* function:

```
ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((dict(dataframe),zip(res1,res2)))
```

This way, you are telling *from_tensor_slices()* to zip labels into a new array of shape *(N, 2)* instead of concatenating two vectors of shape *(N, 1)* into *(2N, 1)*.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your quick reply! While the solution you proposed did not quite do the trick it pointed me in the right direction! Instead of `zip()` you have to put `res1` and `res2` in a new dataframe: `result_dataframe=dataframe[["result1","result2"]]`